How might a fuzzy logic rice cooker actually use fuzzy logic?
This rice cooker purports to use Advanced Fuzzy Logic.
I understand it's hard to know how this specific rice cooker works, so my question is how might fuzzy logic for a rice cooker work in general? What would a simple computer program for implementing fuzzy logic for cooking rice look like?
It would be really helpful to get an idea of what this could look like, since I'm curious about applications of fuzzy logic. It seems there are many kinds of fuzzy logic and I suspect someone familiar with the area would be able to narrow down to just a few that may be relevant for this kind of control task.
Some background that might help:

The way an inexpensive rice cooker typically works is by a simple mechanical process: as the water is absorbed and evaporated, heat disperses less, the pan gets hotter, and a thermometer is used to know when to stop heating. Expressed as a program: if temperature > 100 /*Celsius*/ then stop_heating().
The fuzzy logic rice cooker likely uses more inputs than just temperature when determining when to stop heating (such as pressure and duration).

The shape of an answer could be a short program that starts something like this:
# using Gödel–Dummett logic (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-fuzzy/#GodeLogi)
loop:
   keep_heating()
   pressure = get_pressure() # between 0 and 1 ("fuzzy" ?)
   temperature = get_temperature() # between 0 and 1
   if should_stop(pressure, temperature):
      break

# TODO: make it more fuzzy. Maybe something is fuzzy in `should_stop`?
```


FYI your link to the 'rice cooker' instead links to a cast iron pot.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_control_system

Fixed link to the rice cooker product description
